# Changing Position of Admob BannerView on iOS

Tags: ios, admob

I've got my AdMob banners all setup and working but I'm having some trouble positioning them.

This is the code that's in presently to load the bannerview, but I can't quite place how to move it (let's assume to a position of 100, 100)

Can anyone help?

Regards
David

```
  bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeFullBanner];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"a14ff98b8ab890d";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
  [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(100,
                                 100,
                                 bannerView_.bounds.size.width,            
                                 bannerView_.bounds.size.height)];
```

Comment: Where would I place that? :) At the start of the provided code:?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `origin` to your `bannerView_`

```
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0); //Update the X and Y origin to what you need, ex: (0.0, 204.0)
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];
```